# Compiled TypeScript using systemjs not logging to console

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm learning TypeScript. In the course I'm taking, the teacher suggests using systemjs to import modules. I have systemjs installed and configured, but my compiled TypeScript doesn't seem to be working properly. I have a console.log call that is not showing up.

I've tried putting a console.log call into the compiled .js file, outside of the "define" statement, and it works, so I don't think it's an issue with my references to files. It's just the console.log call inside the second define that doesn't work.

Here is my TypeScript:

```js
/// <reference path="06lesson_circle.ts"/>
/// <reference path="06lesson_rectangle.ts"/>

import CircleMath = MyMath.Circle;

import { pi, calculateCircumference} 
    from "./math/06modules_Circle";

console.log(calculateCircumference(10));
```

And here is the transpiled JavaScript:

```js
var MyMath;
(function (MyMath) {
    var Circle;
    (function (Circle) {
        var pi = 3.1415;
        function calculateCircumference(diameter) {
            return diameter * pi;
        }
        Circle.calculateCircumference = calculateCircumference;
    })(Circle = MyMath.Circle || (MyMath.Circle = {}));
})(MyMath || (MyMath = {}));
var MyMath;
(function (MyMath) {
    function calculateRectangle(width, length) {
        return width * length;
    }
    MyMath.calculateRectangle = calculateRectangle;
})(MyMath || (MyMath = {}));
define("math/06modules_Circle", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
    "use strict";
    exports.__esModule = true;
    exports.pi = 3.1415;
    function calculateCircumference(diameter) {
        return diameter * exports.pi;
    }
    exports.calculateCircumference = calculateCircumference;
});
/// <reference path="06lesson_circle.ts"/>
/// <reference path="06lesson_rectangle.ts"/>
define("06lesson", ["require", "exports", "math/06modules_Circle"], function (require, exports, _06modules_Circle_1) {
    "use strict";
    exports.__esModule = true;
    console.log(_06modules_Circle_1.calculateCircumference(10));
});
```

I don't get any error messages; just a blank console. I'm not sure what else to try in order to troubleshoot this, as I have no prior experience with systemjs and only what I've learned of TypeScript in the course, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is because while you have defined the module (your file), you have not reference it thus the code it contains is not being processed.

That's why your `console.log()` is not being executed.

Comment: But as I said in my question, if I put a console.log() outside the define block in that file, it does get called. So I don't think that's the reason.

Comment: The file is loaded does not mean it is executed. It is within a `define()` function.
Until you import that module, the content will not be executed.

Comment: by the way, this has nothing to do with TypeScript. It is just JavaScript.

Comment: So what do I do within TypeScript to get it to compile such that it runs? If I just move the console.log outside the define, it won't work because the reference to _06modules_Circle_1 is no longer valid.